# Configuring Logstash for Docker

Tags: docker, logstash, docker-swarm

I'm new in Docker and I'm having problems running a simple logstash.conf with Docker.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.0.0
RUN rm -f ~/desktop/docker_logstash/logstash.conf
```

Logstash.conf:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "~/desktop/filename.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }

}

filter {
    grok {
        match => {
            "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"
        }
    }



}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Docker commands:

```
docker build -t logstashexample .
docker run logstashexample
```

I can build the container but when I run it it is stuck on:

> Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties. 
>   [2017-11-22T11:08:23,040][INFO][logstash.inputs.beats    ] Beats inputs: Starting input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5044"} 
>   [2017-11-22T11:08:24,501][INFO][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>125}
>   [2017-11-22T11:08:24,520][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started [2017-11-22T11:08:24,593][INFO][org.logstash.beats.Server] Starting server on port: 5044
>   [2017-11-22T11:08:25,054][INFO ][logstash.agent] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Include your `docker run` command in your question please, it might be relevant here.

Comment: @bluescores done

Comment: Are you sure it's "stuck"? When you run a container, by default you attach your session to that container. Any output from the container will appear in your session's stdout. Try adding the -d flag (detach) like `docker run -d logstashexample`, maybe that's the behavior you're after.

Comment: @bluescores  I got this output from the docker shell:
529320c65ab3f36152e2e3fc731c7772fc268d0dca4493ee9c743a41a1d4e1d4

Comment: Correct, that is the container ID. `docker ps` and you should see that the container is running. Read up on the docker cli commands and options [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/).

Comment: But how can I get the logstash output? It is suppose to output it to the shell, right? @bluescores

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159583/discussion-between-slfl-and-bluescores).